# Speaking url (realurl) links not rendering in extbase extension

Tags: typo3, extbase, realurl

I am developing an extbase extension to expose the site menu structure in json format. PageRepository gives me the relevant page uids and titles so the only remaining challenge is building correct URLs. I am using typoLink to do this but instead of getting speaking urls (which are rendered correctly if I browse the site) the output is in the form of index.php?id=[uid]. Here is my code:

```
$data = $this->pageRepository->getMenu(1);
$this->cObj = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObj;
$retval = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $row)
{
    $pageUid = $row['uid'];
    $conf = array('parameter'=>$pageUid, 'returnLast'=>'url');
    $uri = $this->cObj->typoLink('', $conf);
    array_push($retval, array('title' => $row['title'], 'url' => $uri));
}
```

Realurl 2.3.2

Typo3 8.7.11

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a pageType to render your Extbase JSON response, have you checked if `config.tx_realurl_enable = 1` is set for this pageType?

Comment: That did the trick. I had previously defined a new page type in the template to disable header code and add content-type headers. I guess the default for tx_realurl_enable is 0. Things started working as expected as soon as I added the key/val to the config section.